# Find the country name

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, english

Which country’s name is hidden in the lines below?

```
75  Wathd,tsshtf    
74  M,m,aWNds    
77  Tcfffa,nIuts    
76  O,ycd,ycj    
80  Yh,ys,ys    
73  Edinmohwtto
```

Comment: Just to say, I really liked this puzzle! As soon as I realised what was going on (76 was my aha moment) I had to stop midway through brushing my teeth and pick up a laptop to put it all down! A proper buzz - thank you :)

Comment: PS Think there's one tiny typo in the last line (the 'n' should be a 't')

Comment: @Stiv Nice job solving this one! I was worried it would be too difficult. Thanks for the kudos, and good catch on the tiny typo (I'll leave it there for posterity).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is:

> **SWEDEN**

Because each line represents:

> The first letters of words (plus the punctuation) in the opening line of a song by Swedish pop superstars, *ABBA*. The number is the year the song was released.

*75  Wathd,tsshtf*

> *Where are those happy days, they seem so hard to find* = **SOS** (1975)

*74  M,m,aWNds*

> *My, my, at Waterloo Napoleon did surrender* = **WATERLOO** (1974)

*77  Tcfffa,nIuts*

> *They came flying from far away, now I'm under their spell* = **EAGLE** (1977)

*76  O,ycd,ycj*

> *Oh, you can dance, you can jive* = **DANCING QUEEN** (1976)

*80  Yh,ys,ys*

> *You hate, you scream, you swear* = **ELAINE** (1980)

*73  Edinmohwtto*

> *Every day in [the] morning on her way to the office* = **NINA, PRETTY BALLERINA** (1973)

One final step:

> Take the initial letters of the song titles, and sure enough they spell **SWEDEN**!

Comment: Really?! Somebody chose to downvote a correct and perfectly explained answer, with no explanation?! That just seems spiteful... What a waste.